# XML root element missing issue c#

Tags: c#, xml

i am just passing xml to UPS web service and web service return some data. some time i am getting error **root element missing** here is my routine code which throw this error. please guide me how to fix it.

```
public ShippingAcceptResult ShippingAccept(string acceptDigestCode)
{
    requestType = ShipRequestTypes.ShipAccept;

    xmlRequest = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
    xmlRequest.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
     <ShipmentAcceptRequest>
       <Request>
          <TransactionReference>
             <CustomerContext>TR01</CustomerContext>
             <XpciVersion>1.0001</XpciVersion>
          </TransactionReference>
          <RequestAction>ShipAccept</RequestAction>
          <RequestOption>01</RequestOption>
       </Request>
       <ShipmentDigest>" + acceptDigestCode + "</ShipmentDigest></ShipmentAcceptRequest>");

    byte[] bb = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(string.Format(XML_CONNECT, sAccessCode.Trim(), sUserId.Trim(), sPassword.Trim()));

    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    ms.Write(bb, 0, bb.Length);
    xmlRequest.Save(ms);
    bb = ms.ToArray();
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    xmlRespone = new XmlDocument();
    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadData(UPS_URL, "POST", bb)));
    string serverName = (testMode) ? "wwwcie" : "www";

    serverName = string.Format(UPS_SERVICE_URL, serverName, ShipRequestTypes.ShipAccept);
    xmlRespone.LoadXml(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadData(serverName, "POST", bb)));
    //xmlRespone.Save(@"d:\shippingresponseAccept.xml");
    return new ShippingAcceptResult(xmlRespone);
}
```

the most funniest this if i add a thread.sleep() at the beginning of the routine then error is not happening. please guide me in details where the problem is in code. thanks

### EDIT

this line throwing error `xmlRespone.LoadXml(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(wc.UploadData(serverName, "POST", bb)));`

Comment: Where in the code are you getting the error?

Comment: At which line is error happening?

Comment: do not know at which line error occur...because when i debug line by line then error does not occur but when i run the code without debugging then error occur in that routine. i am in confusion.

Comment: when i add thread.sleep at top of the routine then no error occur.

Comment: Could you post a sample response from "wc.UploadData(serverName, "POST", bb)"? You're probably not  receiving a valid XML in response

Comment: So the problem lies obviously outside this code... if a `Sleep` prevents it from happening, I may check that the server I'm hitting with `wc.UploadData` is not being hit many times in a row (maybe by a loop calling `ShippingAccept` quickly in succession) and returning some error condition (and not XML), but it could be any other thing actually